# Extract Names from E-Mails in a textarea javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, textarea, extract

I've got a simple textarea in an html form. That textarea can be filled with multiple e-mail addresses. I need a way to extract the Names from the e-mail addresses from the first textarea into the other textarea, for example:

`john.doe@test.com, J.doe@mail.com, ...`

and i need an output like this: `john doe, J doe, ...`

My current html code is as following:

```html
<html>
<body>

Insert e-mail addresses:<br>

<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="myTextarea2"></textarea>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Extract Names</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Took me 10 seconds to find a duplicate. Please do some research before asking. Just split on space and loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Thank you very much, but I've still got the problem that it doesn't work with multiple e-mail addresses which are separated with " ; ". I'm a programming beginner. I've got an idea that one could solve this problem with a while loop, but i just don't have any clue right now to be honest

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/yjbd0q7y/ `function myFunction() {
  var addrArr = document.querySelector("#myTextarea").value.split(", ");
  var names = addrArr.map(function(name) {
    return name.match(/^([^@]*)@/)[1];
  });
  document.querySelector("#myTextarea2").value=names;
}  `

Comment: wow, thank you very much! saved my day :)